# jquery sourcemap prepends hostname

Tags: jquery, web-applications, source-maps

I am linking to cloudflares cdnjs like so

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jquery.min.js is pointing to the map like so

```
// Inside jquery.min.js
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map
```

Which works fine, but then it prepends my hostname when trying to fetch the source-map.

```
https://www.MYWEBSITE.com/https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.map
```

Which causes the GET to error out. Any thoughts?

**Update**
The problem seems to only be occurring in Chrome (29.0.1547.49). Works fine in Safari and Firefox

Comment: Does this happen with all browsers? With 30 seconds thought on the matter, it seems like a browser bug?

Comment: You are probably correct. It works fine in safari and firefox. I will update the question to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a browser bug, then. The source maps feature seems to be broken with schema-relative URIs. Please [report it](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en).

Only workaround I can think of is to use the complete URI for the original JS reference when debugging.

Comment: reported it. Can't believe I didn't try a different browser ;/ Problem solving 101. Thanks!